# Windows phone:Get email id of user using facebook graph api

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, facebook-sdk-4.0

```
var client = new Facebook.FacebookClient(this.fbLoginButton.CurrentSession.AccessToken);
dynamic result = await client.GetTaskAsync("me");
var currentUser = new Facebook.Client.GraphUser(result);
this.userInfo.Text = this.BuildUserInfoDisplay(currentUser);



private string BuildUserInfoDisplay(Facebook.Client.GraphUser user)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("In user info display");
    var userInfo = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    userInfo.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}", user.Name));
}
```

Some One please tell me how to get email id the user using facebook graph api in windows

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the `email` permission during the login. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-email
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#login

Comment: given email permission but how to access ??

<facebookControls:LoginButton 
    x:Name="fbLoginButton" 
    Grid.Row="2" 
    Margin="50"
    Permissions="email,user_location,user_birthday,user_about_me"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" ApplicationId="738259606271546" SessionStateChanged="LoginButton_SessionStateChanged" />

Comment: As I don't know the C# SDK, I guess it's `user.email`. Look at the docs of the SDK and the FB docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading